# How to select unique nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I found [this page](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) describing the Muenchian method, but I think I'm applying it wrong.

Consider that this would return a set of ages:

```
/doc/class/person/descriptive[(@name='age')]/value
```

> 1..2..2..2..3..3..4..7

But I would like a nodeset only one node for each age.

> 1..2..3..4..7

Each of these seem to return all of the values, instead of unique values:

```
/doc/class/person/descriptive[(@name='age')][not(value=preceding-sibling::value)]/value
/doc/class/person/descriptive[(@name='age')]/value[not(value=preceding-sibling::value)]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Oops, it looks like the example I followed was *not* the Muenchian method - instead what the author was contrasting it against.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<root>
    <item type='test'>A</item>
    <item type='test'>B</item>
    <item type='test'>C</item>
    <item type='test'>A</item>
    <item type='other'>A</item>
    <item type='test'>B</item>
    <item type='other'>D</item>
    <item type=''>A</item>
</root>
```

And the XPath:

```
//preceding::item/preceding::item[not(.=preceding-sibling::item)]/text()
```

Results:
A B C D

**EDIT**:
As mousio commented this doesn't capture the last item in a list if it's the only time it appears. Taking that and Fëanor's comment into account, here's a better solution:

```
/root/item[not(.=preceding-sibling::item)]
```

Comment: Obviously, you can use additional XPath to restrict based on the type attribute or other data in your actual file. I just had it in there during my quick test.

Comment: Also note that "item" in the XPath isn't a keyword, it's the name of the element in the XML document that the preceding:: and preceding-sibling:: axes are working on.

Comment: I dont think the use of // is helpful here given the structure is given so we know all the item nodes, and only item nodes, appear under the root node, this is better: root/item[. != preceding-sibling]

Comment: Note that this does not match a unique item that only appears last in the list! (e.g. adding an `X` item at the end of the provided sample input still yields results `A B C D` – no `X`)

Comment: @mousio, Good catch. Editing the answer to provide for this case.

Comment: Correct now, but I feel that the attribute predicate in the question is not to be ignored. [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt/227765#227765) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt/1112524#1112524) do address this explicitly…

Comment: @BQ. Thank you for the solution... :-) I had the same problem and was searching for the solution since two days. It is amazing to see that "preceding-sibling::item" will get all the preceding items and check the condition with all of them. Can you also suggest some URL wherein I can practice with XSLT and XPath.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the Muenchian version of BQ's answer using his data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="item-by-value" match="item" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/item"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', normalize-space(.)))">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform gives

A
  B
  C
  D

1. The `key()` lookup above in the template for `item` returns a nodeset containing all the `item` elements with the same string value as the context node.
2. If you apply a function that expects a single node to a nodeset, it will operate on the first node in that nodeset.
3. All calls to `generate-id()` are guaranteed to generate the same ID for a given node during a single pass through a document.
4. Therefore, the test will be true if the context node is the same node as the first one returned by the `key()` call.

Comment: with a little tweaking of the match and use parameters this worked like a charm inside a for-each element; thanks!

Comment: @ChuckB if an item element has a value that contains two spaces it's not picked up (for example  <item type='test'>A  B</item>). Any idea why is that?

Comment: How does `position()` work in this example? Say you started out with a nodeset of `A, A, A, B, B, B` and got it down to `A, B`, would there be a way to get the new `position()` of `A` and `B`, which should be `1` for `A` and `2` for `B`?

Answer (score 5):

For those who still look for a select distinct in XSLT:

With XSLT 2.0,
you can use
"distinct-values(/doc/class/person/descriptive[(@name='age')]/value)"

Answer (score 2):

The Muenchian method uses keys to create a unique list of items from the node set. For your data, the key would look like this:

```
<!-- Set the name to whatever you want -->
<xsl:key name="PeopleAges" match="/doc/class/person/descriptive[@name = 'age']/value" use="." />
```

From there, I would personally use `xsl:apply-templates` but you can use the following `select` attribute in other places:

```
<!-- you can change `apply-templates` to: `copy-of` or `for-each`. -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="/doc/class/person/descriptive[@name = 'age']/value[count(. | key('PeopleAges', .)[1]) = 1]" />
```

The accompanying match for the above is much simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="person/descriptive[@name = 'age']/value">
    <strong>Age: </strong><xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing a reference to 'descriptive' right after the preceding-value? Some thing like the following:

```
/doc/class/person/descriptive[(@name='age')][not(value=preceding-sibling::descriptive[@name='age']/value)]/value
```

(Haven't tested it)