# Selecting the unique values from multiple attributes in an XML document using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<League>
  <Week Date="26/04/2010 19:00">
    <Fixture Id="542" HomeTeamId="371" HomeTeam="London Raiders Green" AwayTeamId="13" AwayTeam="Richmond Swingers" />
    <Fixture Id="543" HomeTeamId="45" HomeTeam="Spartans" AwayTeamId="15" AwayTeam="Panthers" />
    <Fixture Id="544" HomeTeamId="370" HomeTeam="Fat Cats" AwayTeamId="381" AwayTeam="London Raiders Orange" />
  </Week>
  <Week Date="27/04/2010 19:00">
    <Fixture Id="548" HomeTeamId="3" HomeTeam="The Mob" AwayTeamId="81" AwayTeam="London Raiders Red" />
    <Fixture Id="549" HomeTeamId="373" HomeTeam="Intellect" AwayTeamId="83" AwayTeam="Tornadoes" />
  </Week>
</League>
```

What I would like to do is get a unique list of all the Team Ids within that XML, but the problem is that team ids can either appear in the `HomeTeamId` or the `AwayTeamId` attributes in the fixture nodes.  So I'm struggling to use the standard grouping methods ([Grouping using the Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) or [selecting unique nodes by checking the preceding sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt)).

I can get a list of all the ids this way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Fixture/@HomeTeamId | //Fixture/@AwayTeamId">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But of course when the teams appear in more than one fixture, their id is output more than once using the for-each above.

My ultimate aim is to output a list of fixtures grouped by each team, but I'm struggling with the XSLT here - it's making my brain hurt...  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that works even if the ids for the teams come from a set of many differently-named attributes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem to use Muenchian grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Fixture/@HomeTeamId | Fixture/@AwayTeamId" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="(//Fixture/@HomeTeamId | //Fixture/@AwayTeamId)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', .)[1])]">
          <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </head>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wouldn't use a for-each but instead do apply-templates but as you already had a for-each in your sample I kept that to show how to use the Muenchian grouping with that.

Comment: Brilliant.  It was that union that I was missing on the select within the for-each when I was trying to use Muenchian grouping.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation produces the unique team ids even if their values belonged to any number of differently named attributes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTeamById"
  match="@*[name()=document('')/*/my:teamIdNames/*]" use="."/>

 <my:teamIdNames>
   <name>HomeTeamId</name>
   <name>AwayTeamId</name>
 </my:teamIdNames>

 <xsl:variable name="vAttrNames" select=
  "document('')/*/my:teamIdNames/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "//Fixture/@*[name()=$vAttrNames]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "@*[name()=document('')/*/my:teamIdNames/*]
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kTeamById', .)[1])
     ]
 ">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<League>
    <Week Date="26/04/2010 19:00">
        <Fixture Id="542" HomeTeamId="371"
        HomeTeam="London Raiders Green"
        AwayTeamId="13" AwayTeam="Richmond Swingers"/>
        <Fixture Id="543" HomeTeamId="45"
        HomeTeam="Spartans" AwayTeamId="15"
        AwayTeam="Panthers"/>
        <Fixture Id="544" HomeTeamId="370"
        HomeTeam="Fat Cats" AwayTeamId="381"
        AwayTeam="London Raiders Orange" />
    </Week>
    <Week Date="27/04/2010 19:00">
        <Fixture Id="548" HomeTeamId="3"
        HomeTeam="The Mob" AwayTeamId="81"
        AwayTeam="London Raiders Red"/>
        <Fixture Id="549" HomeTeamId="373"
        HomeTeam="Intellect" AwayTeamId="83"
        AwayTeam="Tornadoes"/>
    </Week>
</League>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
371<br/>13<br/>45<br/>15<br/>370<br/>381<br/>3<br/>81<br/>373<br/>83<br/>
```

**Do note**:

**This solution doesn't assume** that the sources of the ids for the teams come just from the attributes named `HomeTeamId` and `AwayTeamId`.

**In fact, any variable set of names can be used** (and included in a separate document), so this is a very powerful, generic solution.

Comment: +1 Because this answers the question's title much better, besides the OP original problem.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed a very powerful generic solution.  Thanks.  I've +1ed because of that as well, even though I have used Martin's solution because I think that I'll have a better chance of remembering how his works when I come back and have to look at it years later! :)