# XSLT 1 Distinct select on ancestors

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I've had a bit of trouble working out the correct statement to return a unique list of values. The following path is just an example, which is similar to my dilemma.

```
/Root/Books/Book/Writers/Writer/Fullname
```

What would return the unique list of "fullnames", keeping in mind that the assumption here is there are multiple writers for each book and they may be involved in multiple books.

Thanks for your help

Here is an example of the XML document

```
<Root>
    <Books>
        <Book>
            <Title>Book A</Title>
            <Writers>
                <Writer>Jon Smith</Writer>
                <Writer>Peter Smith</Writer>
            </Writers>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Book B</Title>
            <Writers>
                <Writer>Jon Smith</Writer>
                <Writer>Peter Smith</Writer>
                <Writer>James Bloggs</Writer>
            </Writers>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Book C</Title>
            <Writers>
                <Writer>Bob Peterson</Writer>
                <Writer>Peter Smith</Writer>
                <Writer>James Bloggs</Writer>
            </Writers>
        </Book>
    </Books>
</Root>
```

What I'd like to return is a list of the different writers.

Jon Smith
Peter Smith
James Bloggs
Bob Peterson.

It's trickier because there are multiple books with multiple writers.

Comment: Very hard to say without seeing the input xml.

Comment: [Grouping Using the Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Comment: I've been playing around with the "preceding" statement a bit but still cant seem to get it. Here is an example XML document:

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select unique nodes in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

Follow Robert's [link](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) and just do the first step of the grouping recipe:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select='Root/Books/Book/Writers/Writer[not(preceding::Writer = .)]'/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for your help, I was only just off. I had a feeling that was only going to return unique lists of writers PER book, not as a collection of books. Thanks, learnt something new with XSLT.

Comment: To get the same per book, replace `preceding` with `preceding-sibling`.