# Need to fetch distinct elements through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

I have a list of table elements under element named Query that may duplicate, I need to fetch distinct table elements (not its value but the tag/element name itself.

`/ShopArea/Connection/Query/*` lists the table names including duplicates.

Below is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ShopArea.xslt"?>
<ShopArea>
<Connection name="Connection1">
    <Report date="25-09-2011">

        <Query id="1">
            <TABLE1>1.1</TABLE1>
            <TABLE2>1.2</TABLE2>
            <TABLE3>1.3</TABLE3>
        </Query>
        <Query id="2">
            <TABLE21>2.1</TABLE21>
            <TABLE22>2.2</TABLE22>
            <TABLE23>2.3</TABLE23>
        </Query>
    </Report>

    <Report date="26-09-2011">
        <Query id="1">
            <TABLE1>26 1.1</TABLE1>
            <TABLE2>26 1.2</TABLE2>
            <TABLE3>26 1.3</TABLE3>
        </Query>
        <Query id="2">
            <TABLE21>26 2.1</TABLE21>
            <TABLE22>26 2.2</TABLE22>
            <TABLE23>26 2.3</TABLE23>
        </Query>
    </Report>
</Connection>
</ShopArea>
```

[image: List of elements including duplicates]

I refered [How to select unique nodes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt/227805#227805) but I'm not able to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0. This transformation uses simple [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kChildByName" match="Query/*"
  use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Query/*
       [generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kChildByName', name())[1])
       ]">
     <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ShopArea>
    <Connection name="Connection1">
        <Report date="25-09-2011">
            <Query id="1">
                <TABLE1>1.1</TABLE1>
                <TABLE2>1.2</TABLE2>
                <TABLE3>1.3</TABLE3>
            </Query>
            <Query id="2">
                <TABLE21>2.1</TABLE21>
                <TABLE22>2.2</TABLE22>
                <TABLE23>2.3</TABLE23>
            </Query>
        </Report>
        <Report date="26-09-2011">
            <Query id="1">
                <TABLE1>26 1.1</TABLE1>
                <TABLE2>26 1.2</TABLE2>
                <TABLE3>26 1.3</TABLE3>
            </Query>
            <Query id="2">
                <TABLE21>26 2.1</TABLE21>
                <TABLE22>26 2.2</TABLE22>
                <TABLE23>26 2.3</TABLE23>
            </Query>
        </Report>
    </Connection>
</ShopArea>
```

**the wanted, correct result (all different names of elements that are children of a `Query`) is produced**:

```
TABLE1
TABLE2
TABLE3
TABLE21
TABLE22
TABLE23
```

**II. XSLT 2.0: This transformation uses** `<xsl:for-each-group>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="Report/Query/*"
                         group-by="name()">
      <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key(), '&#xA;'"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent! It works, but this code (Muenchian grouping) looks way too complicated. Will need a while to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Arvind Singh: You are welcome. Muenchian grouping is the de facto standard for highly efficient XSLT 1.0 grouping. To understand it better, just follow the link on the first line of this answer -- this leads to Jeni Tennison's excellent Muenchian Grouping page.