# XQuery: How to select unique nodes

Tags: xml, xquery

I have to get all present values of a certain node.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes) answered question.
My XML file looks different. So I have multiple elements having the same name..

```
  <instance>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0.72</value>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0.72</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>22</value>
  </instance>
  <instance>
    <value>10000000</value>
    <value>0.72</value>
    <value>0</value>
    <value>0.72</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>22</value>
  </instance>
  <instance>
    <value>20000000</value>
    <value>0.64</value>
    <value>-0.04</value>
    <value>0.68</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>22</value>
  </instance>
```

Following query is selecting each `5th` value:

```
new XQuery("doc('database/dataset.xml')/dataset/body/instances/instance/value[5]")
```

With the result :

```
<value>2</value>

<value>1</value>

<value>1</value>
```

How can i incorporate the accepted answer of the linked question to get the required output:

```
<value>2</value>

<value>1</value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest an alternate answer since this is XQuery, which allows element constructors. But this only works in case the identity of the nodes is irrelevant:

```
for $value in distinct-values(
  doc('database/dataset.xml')/dataset/body/instances/instance/value[5]
)
return <value>{$value}</value>
```

Comment: Wow that's a very fast approach!. I tend to accept this.. (even if the first answer answers the exact question..) As the first one seems to produce much more overhead (It runs in an exception (thrown from the XML database.. I have not figured out why)). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it would look like

```
doc('database/dataset.xml')
/dataset
/body
/instances
/instance[ not(value[5] = preceding-sibling::instance/value[5]) ]
/value[5]
```

(using the edited accepted answer trick)