# Get list of child nodes based on parent node id, without any duplicates

Tags: regex, xml, xpath

I ran out of ides how to avoid this 'duplicate' node situation.

**Problem:**
Consider, we have following xml:

```
<root>
 <cities>
  <city id = "1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "2">
    <name>DEF</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
 <cities>
</root>
```

What I have to archive is avoid duplicates from that. So on  output i want to see and output of 2 nodes:

```
 <city id = "1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "2">
    <name>DEF</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </city>
```

I tried many solutions before posting this (like `//*:city[@name='ABC']/@name`)
but it returns list with all duplicates.(in this case 3)

Any ideas how to solve?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you check my updated answer, it will satisfy your question. if not edit the Question to solve it.

Comment: Truly updated solution works, however implementation of that doesn't work out well in my use case.

Comment: an upvote for your question related to parent and child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sample `HTML | XML` test the below `XPaths` [**here...**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)

```
<cities>
<city>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <value>2</value>
</city>
<city>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <value>1</value>
</city>
<city>
  <name>DEF</name>
  <value>2</value>
</city>
<city>
  <name>AB</name>
  <value>1</value>
</city>
<city>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <value>1</value>
</city>
<cities>
```

Distinct data from Child elements list:

> ```
>  //cities/descendant::city[not(.=preceding-sibling::city)]
> ```

Distinct node`Values` form parent `City` Siblings.

> ```
>  //cities/descendant::city[not(./value=preceding-sibling::city/value)]/value
> ```

Distinct node`Names` from parent `City` Siblings.

> ```
>  //cities/descendant::city[not(./name=preceding-sibling::city/name)]/name
> ```

---

[`nodes of same level`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227805/5081877) with distinct data.

```
<root>
    <item type='test'>A</item>
    <item type='test'>B</item>
    <item type='test'>C</item>
    <item type='test'>A</item>
    <item type='other'>A</item>
    <item type='test'>B</item>
    <item type='other'>D</item>
</root>
```

> ```
> //preceding::item/preceding::item[not(.=preceding-sibling::item)]/text()
> ```

---

Updated answer with node attribute value:

```
<root>
 <cities>
  <city id = "1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "3">
    <name>DEF</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
  <city id = "4">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </city>
   <city id = "2">
    <name>DE</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </city>
 <cities>
</root>
```

XPaths:

> ```
>  //cities/city/following::city[not(./@id=following::city/@id)]
>
>  //cities/city/following::city[not(./@id=following::city/@id)]/name
>
>  //cities/city/following::city[not(./@id=following::city/@id)]/value
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the posting the answer. Option 'Distinct nodeNames from parent City Siblings' suitable for me but not so much. There is also and id parameter to that city node. I'll update the example.

Comment: @Reborn answer updated with id also, i wish it will help you.